# How to make the computer pick random words?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Type Speed Test. I want to make a script that picks a random word and then shows it in a input box.

Edit:
i want an array that picks a word whenever i click it

I have no idea how to make it help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Put all the words in an array, and select a random index in array by `Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install *random-words* module:

```
npm install random-words
```

Then

```
var randomWords = require('random-words');
console.log(randomWords());
```

Which outputs, for example:

```
scarecrow
```

Or, if you're in the browser, you could `browserify` that module, or use a custom approach, like this one:

```
function pickRandomWord() {
  var words = []
  words[ 0] = "terrorists"
  words[ 1] = "escapology"
  words[ 2] = "brightwork"
  words[ 3] = "verkrampte"
  words[ 4] = "protectrix"
  words[ 5] = "nudibranch"
  words[ 6] = "grandchild"
  words[ 7] = "newfangled"
  words[ 8] = "flugelhorn"
  words[ 9] = "mythologer"
  words[10] = "pluperfect"
  words[11] = "jellygraph"
  words[12] = "quickthorn"
  words[13] = "rottweiler"
  words[14] = "technician"
  words[15] = "cowpuncher"
  words[16] = "middlebrow"
  words[17] = "jackhammer"
  words[18] = "triphthong"
  words[19] = "wunderkind"
  words[20] = "dazzlement"
  words[21] = "jabberwock"
  words[22] = "witchcraft"
  words[23] = "pawnbroker"
  words[24] = "thumbprint"
  words[25] = "motorcycle"
  words[26] = "cryptogram"
  words[27] = "torchlight"
  words[28] = "bankruptcy"

  // generate a random number between 0 and the words array length
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
  // return the picked index word
  return words[index]
}
```

Comment: npm WARN lasse@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN lasse@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ random-words@1.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 4 packages in 0.637s
found 0 vulnerabilities And require doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean with this comment? Are you developing for the browser?

Comment: sorry if it was unclear. i tried to download the package and used the code but in the console on google says "tst.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at window.onload"

Comment: Ok. You're developing for the browser... Wait a second...

Comment: One option would be using browserify (https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage)...

Comment: Otherwise, you can follow this approach, without using any external module: https://codepen.io/justpete/pen/ogNBPp

Comment: You welcome. I add the approach you choose in the answer, to make it more clear for anybody else...